# JBehave resources not found in reports

Tags: css, jbehave, jbehave-maven-plugin

When I run my test project, the reports are genereted in directory target/jbehave/view as expected.

My problem is that the stylesheets are not found... In the directory target/jbehave/view/style I have a css jbehave.css but the reports generated look for jbehave-core.css

I don't know if I have some versions problem or something else...

Here are the dependencies I use in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-gherkin</artifactId>
      <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave.site</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-site-resources</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
 <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack-view-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

with ${jbehave.version} = 4.1

For the JBehave configuration I use this class:

```
public class TestRunner extends JUnitStories {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public TestRunner() {
        initJBehaveConfiguration();
    }

    private void initJBehaveConfiguration() {
        Class<?> thisClass = this.getClass();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("encoding", "UTF-8");
        useConfiguration(new MostUsefulConfiguration()
                .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(thisClass.getClassLoader()))
                .usePendingStepStrategy(new FailingUponPendingStep())
                .useStepdocReporter(new PrintStreamStepdocReporter())
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
                        .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(thisClass))
                        .withDefaultFormats()
                        .withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.TXT, Format.HTML, Format.XML, Format.STATS)
                        .withCrossReference(new CrossReference())
                        .withViewResources(properties)
                        .withFailureTrace(true))
                .useParameterConverters(new ParameterConverters()
                        .addConverters(new ParameterConverters.DateConverter(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))))
                .useStoryParser(new GherkinStoryParser())
                .useStepMonitor(new SilentStepMonitor()));
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new SpringStepsFactory(configuration(), applicationContext);
    }

    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()), "**/*.story", "**/excluded*.story");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I made it work.

The probleme came from the pom.

Here is one working for me:

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbehave-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbehave-gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>run-stories-as-embeddables</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*Scenarios.java</include>
              </includes>
              <ignoreFailureInStories>true</ignoreFailureInStories>
              <ignoreFailureInView>false</ignoreFailureInView>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack-jbehave-site-resources</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <overwriteReleases>false</overwriteReleases>
              <overwriteSnapshots>true</overwriteSnapshots>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.jbehave.site</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jbehave-site-resources</artifactId>
                  <version>3.3</version>
                  <type>zip</type>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jbehave/view</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack-jbehave-reports-resources</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <overwriteReleases>false</overwriteReleases>
              <overwriteSnapshots>true</overwriteSnapshots>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
                  <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jbehave/view</outputDirectory>
                  <includes>**\/*.css,**\/*.ftl,**\/*.js</includes>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
```